# People search results Webpart

Tags: search-results, people-search

I have created a search results Webpart to display a number of user profiles, but the Web part will only display by rank rather than Ascending (as I have selected in the query properties) . Is there any way to override display by rank?

Here are 3 screen shots with the various properties set to try and display in Selected Property by ascending order. 
[image: CWSP1]
[image: CWSP2]
[image: CWSP3]

Comment: Can you include the "sort by" setting in your search result webpart?

Comment: You can in the query configuration Mark but the webpart only seems to want to display by rank.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. I mean please include the setting or screenshot in the question.

Comment: Edit results web part. Change to advanced mode and click Sort tab. There you can set managed property for ex. First Name Ascending. P.S. Rank is default

Comment: EVT - I did that and the test query works, but the webpart still seems to only be able sort by Rank. The query webpart properties allows you to deselect display by rank, but when I do that no results are shown.

Comment: Include some screenshots in the question please.

Comment: Try set sorting First Name Ascending and click Save ad OK (on query builder and webpart). Save page and reload. Sometimes no results are shown in query builder test.

Comment: Thanks - have resolved it taking this approach and using JSON - http://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/why-are-my-sort-orders-not-working-in-my-sharepoint-2013-search-results-web-part#.V8_OBzj2a70

Answer (score 1):

This approach seems to work - http://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/why-are-my-sort-orders-not-working-in-my-sharepoint-2013-search-results-web-part#.V8_OBzj2a70

Comment: You can do it that way also.